# ¿Cómo abrir una ventana modal y pasar un dato para que se muestre en el formulario de la otra ventana?

Tags: javascript, php, html5

Buen día colegas.

Tengo una idea que consiste en obtener un `id` o dato que contenga el nombre de un elemento y pasarlo a una función `javascript`la cual esta vinculada a un evento `onclick` que hace que abra una ventana modal y que el dato que he pasado se lo pueda mostrar en un campo que va a ser `input type="text" readonly` de un formulario.

ejemplo gráfico:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En sí una idea seria pasarle con php embebido el `id` del elemento a la  función

```
<button class="btn_cotiza" onclick="javascript: cotiza(<?php echo $hgr['id'] ?>)">
```

Y que en la función javascript guardar ese dato en el localStorage para que cuando se abra esa ventana modal mediante un `window.onload` se muestre el dato almacenado en el `<input type="text">` que se formaría parte del formulario. Pero actualmente en las herramientas del programador del navegador específicamente en la consola me sale un error de que la sintaxis está mal antes del cierre del ")" en la línea de la etiqueta button y por lo que he visto en otros sitios la etiqueta button no necesariamente se la cierra, es decir ``.

Alguien tiene idea de o que puede estar mal?

Comment: Lo del button cierralo, es lo normal, pues imagino que querrás poner algo que aparezca en el: `<button>Púlsame</button>`.  En cuanto al error de sintaxis, quizás te falta el `;` al final del echo, no estoy seguro, o sea `echo $hgr['id'];`.

Answer (score 0):

Es sencillo de resolver con **javascript**.

Creas *variables* que se llenen **con la información** que mandas traer, por ejemplo de una tabla para modificar, y después indicas imprimir esos datos, por así decirlo, con el **id** que le coloques a cada campo en el formulario del *modal*.

Aquí estoy enviando desde la vista con la información a mi *modal* con un botón:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info edit" value="<?php echo $persona['id']; ?>" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit">
  <i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i>  
</button>
```

Después con **JQuery** realizo esto:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('click', '.edit', function() {
    var id = $(this).val();
    var i = $('#id' + id).text();
    var first = $('#nombre' + id).text();

    $('#edit').modal('show');
    $('#iid').val(i);
    $('#enombre').val(first);
  });
});
```

Te explico, espero darme a entender :)

Si te das cuenta los valores con **#e** son los `id`_ que les asigné a cada campo de mi formulario modal y los **.val** son las *variables* que se llenaron con la información que se obtuvieron de otra ventana donde tengo una tabla con la información.

Este archivo **javascript** lo tienes que mandar llamar en la vista de donde quieres mandar tus datos para la ventana *modal*.

Espero haberme dado a entender y poder ayudarte con tu duda.

Comment: Si bien tu respuesta puede ser un buen aporte (si le funciona), deberias no hacerla tan larga en cuanto al código, porque no necesita tantos campos de ejemplo para ser igualmente válida, siendo estos, los de tu ejemplo, totalmente distintos de los que el OP (Original Poster) seguramente realiza en su pregunta (el cual omite por falta de código). Te recomiendo editarla de nuevo suprimiendo el código superfluo y repetitivo, dejando sólo lo estrictamente necesario para su comprensión.